# Do we still need to include `kapt com.android.databinding:compiler`

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kapt

I remember Kotlin mentioning in their docs that we need to include `kapt com.android.databinding:compiler:version` in our build.gradle. However I can no longer see this mentioned anywhere, except in some `medium articles` or stack overflow questions. So do we still need to include that if we're using the latest android `gradle plugin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of current [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html), you do not need to specify *kapt* (Kotlin annotation processor) compiler dependenciy, because the *kapt* plugin for Gradle/Maven build takes care of it.

Answer (score 2):

When I migrate kapt to ksp, I find some rules:

1: if your code contains @BindAdapter which is writen in kotlin, you must import kapt in your module!

2: to remove kapt completely, I rewrite those by Java, so I find if your @BindAdaptere writen by java, import kapt in not necessary